# Split the content of textbox into respective individual textboxes at run time in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox

I want the text contents of a `TextBox` to split into respective individual `Textbox` carrying a single character using c# windows application form.

Eg : A single Textbox containing text as-[Orange]

Expected output:- 
in 20 separate textboxes

[o][r][a][n][g][e][][][][][][][][][][][][][][]

Till now I have done this..

`string name = textBox1.Text;
            string str = name;
            int chunkSize = 1;
            Int32 stringLength = str.Length;

```
        for (int i = 0; i < stringLength; i += chunkSize)
        {
            TextBox txtbox = new TextBox();
            //if (i + chunkSize > stringLength)
            //chunkSize = stringLength - i;

            string singlechar = str.Substring(i, chunkSize);

                txtbox.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
                txtbox.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
                txtbox.Font = new Font(txtbox.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
                txtbox.Text = singlechar;
              //txtbox.MaxLength = 1;
                int a = 30;
                int x = (i + 10) * a;
                txtbox.Text = txtbox.Text.ToUpper();
                txtbox.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(x, 100);
                txtbox.BackColor = Color.White;
                txtbox.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(30, 20);
                this.Controls.Add(txtbox);
}`
```

Comment: What have you tried? What are you having trouble with? Are you asking how to examine the characters in a string?

Comment: Why 20  separate textboxes?

Comment: @ps06756: It's probably a class assignment.  Highly-obscure requirements, no redeeming value.

Comment: `textBox2.Text = textBox1.Text[0]; textBox3.Text = textBox1.Text[1];` and so on. Or create for loop for it up to `textBox1.Text.Length`.

Comment: @RobertHarvey My thoughts exactly, was thinking what purpose could this *possibly* serve for an end user?!

Comment: Till now I have done this..

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this:-

```
 textBox1 = mainTextBox.Text[0] ; 
 textBox2 = mainTextBox.Text[1] ; 
  // and so on..
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming other `TextBox`s in `Panel` named panel1 you can write something like :

```
for (int i = 0; i < textBox1.Text.Length; i++)
                ((TextBox)panel1.Controls[i]).Text = textBox1.Text[i].ToString();
```

Comment: @ps06756 it will not work out logical , it is tedious.